# Можно ли выделить из таких строк ФИО при помощи регулярных выражений?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть набор строк с ФИО, притом, строки могут содержать лишние данные в начале и в конце. Шаблон, в общем случае, такой:

```
(ABC) Фамилия Имя Отчество (ABC) ABC
```

В начале может быть (а может и не быть) какой-то текст в скобках (текст в начале всегда в скобках), далее ФИО и после любой другой текст от 0 до 10 символов. Можно ли при помощи регулярного выражения выделить ФИО из такой строки?

Comment: конкретный текст приведите с разными вариантами, а не эти ABC

Answer (score 0):

```php
$text = '(ABC) Фамилия Имя Отчество (ABC) ABC';
/// (\(\S+\)) => (что-то здесь)
/// (.*?) => $2 => фио
/// (\(.*) => всё что идёт после фио начиная с (
$fio = preg_replace('/(\(\S+\))?(.*?)(\(.*)/u','$2',$text);

echo $fio;
```

Comment: `Данный ответ отмечен как «низкокачественный» из-за длины и содержимого.` — движок, пожалуй, прав: данному ответу явно не хватает объяснения того, что в нём предлагается.